# Events from native iPad calendar

Tags: events, ipad, ios, calendar

i want to get events (like a birthday, holidays and etc.) from native iPad calendar, whether there's any chance do it?

Thanks.
Roman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the EventKit framework you can access the calender and read the user's data. You will find Apple's official documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). The [SimpleEKDemo](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) source code was really helpful to me.
If you like video tutorials, you might want to refer to [this one](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-use-event-kit-ui-apple-ios-4-sdk-395865/).

If you want to access the birth dates of people in the user's address book that are saved with the contact details, but not in the calendar, the [AddressBookUI framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) is your choice.

Tf you are however targeting legal holidays, you will need to find an external source. Legal holidays are not supported by default, most likely because they differ from country to country (or even state to state). Apple provides some [iCal calendar files](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/calendars/) with holidays of most countries.

Comment: Björn, 

thank you very much for such detail answer :)

Roman.